# Laravel migrations table is MyISAM table format

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, innodb, laravel-migrations

By default the laravel migrations table is using MYIsam engine. I have changed engine in config/database.php to InnoDB and all my other tables except migrations uses InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

I've verified it now in my app, and all tables have InnoDB storage engine (including `migrations` table). Backup your database, remove `migrations` and see if it will be created now with InnoDB engine

Comment: Your right; I did migrate:refresh and didn’t drop and create